# In a bash script, test error code from a called script

Tags: bash, shell

My bash script (`init.sh`) call another script (`script.sh`) and I want to test the error code from `script.sh` before doing any further action in `init.sh`. 
I thought about testing it with `$?`, but it does not work

My `init.sh` is like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Before call"
docker run -v $PWD:/t -w /t [command]
if [ $? == 1 ]; then
        echo "Issue"
fi
echo "After call"
```

I only got the `Before call` from `stdout` and not the `After call`.

I know for a fact that if I execute `docker run -v $PWD:/t -w /t [command]` alone with wrong arguments, then `echo $?` will rightly display 1.

I was thinking that I do not catch the exit code from `scrip.sh`, but from somewhere else.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is confusing ... you mention `script.sh` but don't call it in your `init.sh`. Anyhow, you might try run `bash -x init.sh` and see what it's actually doing.

Comment: With `set -e`, if the call to `docker` *does* set `$?` to 1, your script will exit before the `if` statement executes, let alone the final `echo` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You running the script with `set -e`. This means that if any command exits with a non zero status, bash will stop executing all subsequent lines. So here, if `docker` exits with status 1, the conditional that follows will not have a chance to run at all. Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Before call"
if ! docker run -v $PWD:/t -w /t [command]; then
        echo "Issue"
fi
echo "After call"
```

This runs the command inside the if test which suppresses the effect of `set -e` I described above and gives you a chance to catch the error. Note this is will also catch all non-zero statuses, not just 1.

Comment: `set -e` is [*not* generally a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: @chepner You are right. In fact, I guess this question itself is an example why.

Comment: The question just seems to overlook that `set -e` was in effect. The actual problems with `set -e` involve more unexpected exits (or failures to exit).

Comment: So, what's the more efficient way? Get rid of the `set -e` or use the solution from @redneb?

Comment: Just get rid of `set -e`. If you really need the script to exit, you can call `exit` explicitly (with the appropriate exit status) from within the `if` statement.

Comment: I use `set -e` only for small trivial scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Bash numeric comparison operator is `-eq`, and not `==`...
So:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Before call"
docker run -v $PWD:/t -w /t [command]
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Issue"
fi
echo "After call"
```

Comment: It's somewhat irrelevant; there aren't any values that `$?`could have that would cause `$? -eq 1` and `$? = 1` (use `=` with `[`, not `==`) to behave differently.

Comment: @Mornor: why did it fail? Because the command did not exit with `-1`? Or why? You should echo the value of `$?`, to test it's value...

Comment: Because I `set -e`, you can check the answer from @redneb

Comment: I see. However, the syntax was incorrect in the first place. The solution for you is probably **not** to use `-e` flag... :-)

Answer (score 1):

`set -e` is generally a bad idea. Sure, it may seem like a good idea to have your script exit automatically  in the event of an unexpected error, but the problem is that `set -e` and you may have different ideas about what constitutes a fatal error.

Instead, do your own error handling.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Before call"
docker run -v $PWD:/t -w /t [command]
docker_status=$?
if [ $docker_status != 0 ]; then
    echo "docker returned: $docker_status"
    exit $docker_status
fi
echo "After call"
```

In this simple code, I've somewhat redundantly saved the value of `$?` to another variable first. This ensures that it is preserved after you start executing other commands that examine, log, or otherwise process the value of `$?`. Also, I'm logging and exiting here on *any* non-zero status, not just 1. In theory, you might take different action for an exit status of 1 than for an exit status of 2, but here we take the same log-then-exit action for any error.